# PySpark can't convert RDD of dicts to DataFrame. Error: can not accept object in type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently using Spark 1.4.1 and can't convert a dict with nested dict to a Spark `DataFrame`. I convert the nested `dict` to a `Row`, but it seems to not accept my schema.

Here is the code to reproduce my error:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext, types as pst
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

example_dict = Row(**{"name": "Mike", "data": Row(**{"age": 10, "like": True})})

example_rdd = sc.parallelize([example_dict])

nested_fields = [pst.StructField("age", pst.IntegerType(), True), 
                 pst.StructField("like", pst.BooleanType(), True)]

schema = pst.StructType([
               pst.StructField("data", pst.StructType(nested_fields), True),
               pst.StructField("name", pst.StringType(), True)
])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(example_rdd, schema)

TypeError: StructType(List(StructField(age,IntegerType,true),StructField(like,BooleanType,true))) can not accept object in type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
```

I am not sure why I receive this error. Here are the objects `rdd` and `schema`:

```
>>> example_rdd.first()
Row(data=Row(age=10, like=True), name='Mike')

>>> schema
StructType(List(StructField(data,StructType(List(StructField(age,IntegerType,true),StructField(like,BooleanType,true))),true),StructField(name,StringType,true)))
```

I am not sure if I am missing something, but it appears that the schema matches the object. Is there a reason why Spark 1.4.1 will not accept Row within a Row?

As a note: this is not an issue in `Spark 2.0.2`, but unfortunately I am on a shared resource using `Spark 1.4.1`, so I need to find a work around for the time being :(. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `Row` is not accepted as `StructType` in Spark 1.4. Accepted types are:

```
pst._acceptable_types[pst.StructType]
```

```
(tuple, list)
```

and Spark makes a naive check:

```
type(obj) not in _acceptable_types[_type]
```

which obviously won't work for `Row` object. Correct condition, which is equivalent to what happens in the current version, would be:

```
isinstance(obj, _acceptable_types[_type])
```

If you want to use nested columns you can use plain Python `tuple`:

```
Row(**{"name": "Mike", "data": (10, True)})
```

or

```
((10, True), "Mike")
```